# Is there any algorithm to mine continuous closed sequences from a sequence database?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-mining

I am working on text compression and I want to use the knowledge of mining closed frequent sequences. The existing algorithms like GSP, CloSpan, ClaSP, Bide mine all frequent sequences both continuous and non continuous. Can you help me in finding such algorithm?

```
For example if the sequence database is 
SID        Sequence
1            CAABC
2            ABCB
3            CABC
4            ABBCA
and minimum support is 2
```

the existing algorithms consider the subsequence 'CB' of sequence with id 1 but I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Modern sequential pattern mining algorithms try to prune the search space to reduce running time. The search space is exponentially larger as a "non-continuous" sub-sequence can be any combination from the input sequences. In your case, the search space is far smaller given that the sequences are continuous i.e. we already know the combinations. So, you can probably make an algorithm for this on your own if you like, and it would still be reasonably faster.

Here's how a crude recursive example could look like:

```
def f(str, database, minSupp):
    freq = 0

    if len(patt) == 0:
        return ""

    #count frequency
    for trans in db:
        if patt in trans:
            freq += 1

    if freq >= minSupp:
        return patt
    else: #break it down
        r = []
        r.append(f(patt[1:], db, minSupp)) #All but the first element
        r.append(f(patt[:-1], db, minSupp)) #All but the last element
        return r
```

This just demonstrates one way of doing it. Of course, it crappy.

To do this much faster, you can use probably write some conditions so that a recursive call is not made in case the pattern is known.

An even faster way would be that you maintain an inverted-index of all patterns and then incrementally update them to create super-patterns using the Apriori-condition. For this, you can refer to some slide-show explaining how the Apriori algorithm works (using your candidate generation method; one example of which is in the algorithm above).

Answer (score 0):

As such no algorithm exists for finding continuous sequences for compression. You can just modify the existing algorithms to mine only continuous sequences. I suggest you to modify BIDE algorithm to find continuous sub sequences only.